# Height of uitableview by number of rows in title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have this code, but it's crashing.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.textLabel.numberOfLines == 2) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return 80;
    }
}
```

Problem is here:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: You don't need to cast to UITableViewCell* as it is already the return type. Moreover, this method only return the cell if it is visible.
What error do you get? Show the crash log

Comment: "warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame." It was showed in console.

Comment: The method want a CGFloat as return yet you return an int.....

Comment: @Tom, you should post that as an answer, because, well, it's the answer.

Comment: Please post the code for your implementation of  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so this question can properly be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the table views data source method `[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` instead:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.textLabel.numberOfLines == 2) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return 80;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is called on cells that are off screen, it will cause them to be prematurely generated, which will be very bad for memory, especially if the tableview is large. A better way to do this would be to figure out the number of lines based on the *data* for the cell, not the view for the cell. E.g. load the data for the cell, and determine the number of lines required to display the string. I assume you're doing this already in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so move that code into its own method and call it from `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @KennyWinker I agree with you, but we would need the OP to show the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath to know where the text is coming from first.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you built some infinite recursion here. When you are asked about the height, your are requesting the cell which is requesting the height ... You should do your calculation based on your data model not on the cell itself.